Is my disk broken?
I have recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop. I have two disks in it. Windows nvme drive, and another ssd drive. I have split the ssd drive in two partitions and installed Ubuntu on one of them. Now I am facing some issues. A couple times my laptop just froze. I was just watching some YouTube when at once my laptop fan turned to max (whatever i do in Ubuntu it is always off) and the whole laptop stopped reacting. There was no sound from the video and I couldn't move the cursor. When I restarted the laptop and wanted to check out the other partition of the disk on which Ubuntu was installed, it gave mounting error. So, I tried the repair file system in the disks app, it worked and I could read the files just fine. It happened several times and it was exactly the same each time. Now the question is that is my ssd is faulty or it is some kind of software issue?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and add which version of Ubuntu you are using. Open the Disks app in Ubuntu and select your SSD. Then click on the 3 vertical dots on the top right corner and click on SMART Data & Self-Test... from the drop down menu. Take a screenshot of the SMART window and add it to your question suing the "picture" icon on the edit question window.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To me it seems as if a few years ago Microsoft made changes that create problems with dual-booting. I used to dual boot but I abandoned dual booting at that time because after every windows update I noticed that my linux partition was nerfed.  If you have an old think-pad, you can swap SSD's quite easily (windows on one, linux on another).  In your situation,  if your SSD is not easily accesible, go with one Operating System or the other.  At this point in time Windows is unneccesary for anything but some games and specialist software applications that don't offer a linux version.  Linux is compatible with microsoft teams/email/office, googledocs, gmail, zoom,  dropbox, whatsapp, signal, steam, spotify, etc.  If you can't find the apps you need in your distros' repository, try flatpak!  If you love your games, steam-powered.com works nicely with Ubuntu and PopOS.

Well, I have a Thinkpad, but it is a "newer" one, so I can't swap the disks so easily. I need to unscrew the whole bottom shell to access disks.
